# Multinomial regression in R: 'groups are empty' warning

Tags: r

I am running a multinomial logistic regression using R, and I am receiving the following warning:

```
> data <- subset(data, !(id %in% c('a','b', 'c', 'd')))
> set.seed(1)
> sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(data), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
> train  <- data[sample, ]
> test <- data[!sample, ]
> model <- multinom(id ~ x + y + z, data=train, maxit = 1000)
Warning message:
In multinom(id ~ x + y +  :
  groups 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' are empty
```

I thought I addressed this issue by subsetting the data and eliminating the empty groups, but I still receive the warning.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an example from ISLR?

In any case, I think this is coming from `id` being a factor thus `multinom` recognizing that there aren't any observations in the data with at those levels. You could try using `droplevels` on ID after subsetting

Comment: Thanks @svenhalvorson, this is the correct answer and fixed the problem. Can you make this an answer so I can give you credit?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is coming from `id` being a factor thus `multinom`recognizing that there aren't any observations in the data with at those levels. You could try using `droplevels` on ID after subsetting

Answer (score 0):

This warning cautions that level `a` of **`factor`**`id` is empty, which is a useful information (e.g. so as not to train you model on a subset of possible outcomes only). The warning disappears when you convert `id` from factor to character: `as.character(id)`.